# Kendo Grid: How to show a dictionary in a column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a datasource where one of the properties of the data object is a dictionary. In my [code](http://dojo.telerik.com/ULeSu) I am showing it as a nested object. I am unable to get it displayed in the grid. I am using ng-repeat in the column template.

Please help !!!

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you solve your issue? If yes, could you please mark my reply as an answer? That way, people who find the question using Google can have more assurance that the answer is correct. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the angular templates are supported only for ["rowTemplate" option](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/the-grid-widget#templates) of the grid as mentioned [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#template-directives). Please check the example below of using row template:

- [Grid: row template with ng-repeat](http://dojo.telerik.com/ULeSu/3)

**Edit:** It seems that the column templates are supported as well from some time. Here is the updated column template:

```
template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="(key, val) in dataItem.ParamObj">{{key}}: {{val}}</li></ul>'}
```